# Coverage.py not giving valid results

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, coverage.py

I was hoping someone could explain how coverage.py works since after reading the documentation on it I am still rather confused.  I am attempting to figure out code coverage by a `TestCase` class and the results haven't been very logical, particularly since after commenting out large chunks of tests the percent missing remains the same. I am working in the community version of PyCharm and haven't been able to find any alternatives to coverage.py so if you could recomend another option that would be appreciated too.

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone can help: you've given no details.

Comment: At the beginning of my testing class I created a coverage object, started it and at the end ended it, saved it and created a report with cov.report(file=document), a report was sent but the numbers don't add up.